# Blur text input fields when click on google captcha

Tags: jquery, ios, captcha, recaptcha

I have been searching the forum for this question but haven't found any answers...

I have google (re)captcha set up and working fine in my login form. But in my smartphone (iphone 6s plus) and also in all other smart phones I would like the smartphone safari keyboard to slide down (blur the input field) when the captcha is active.

I need all screen space possible for my users to see all the captcha images. The keyboard is unnessecary when the captcha window is open.

So how would I achieve this? It seems like there is no click callbacks in google captcha.

Thanks in advance!

/Daniel

Comment: Do you run a function to open the captcha?

Answer (score 0):

When you focus on the captcha, youll have to blur it again to hide the keyboard.

```
$('.captcha').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).blur();
}
```